# Excel vba percentile worksheetfunction function with collection argument

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to call `Application.Worksheetfunction.Percentile(resultColl)` where `resultColl` is a `Collection`?

I tried it and it returns a `Unable to get Percentile property of the WorksheetFunction class` error.

**EDIT:**

I tried to first convert that collection to array:

```
Function convertToArray(resultColl As Collection)
    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(1 To resultColl.Count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To resultColl.Count
        resultArray(i) = resultColl.Item(i)
    Next

    convertToArray = resultArray
End Function
```

and use that array inside `Percentile` function:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile( _
            convertToArray(clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses), 0.99)
```

But now it returns a `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error at `convertToArray` function, even though in this test example I created, the function works fine:

```
Sub testConvert()  'this works fine
    Dim testColl As Collection
    Set testColl = New Collection

    testColl.Add "apple"
    testColl.Add "orange"
    testColl.Add "pineapple"

    Dim tempArray() As Variant
    tempArray = convertToArray(testColl)

    MsgBox (tempArray(1))
End Sub
```

`clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses` is a `Collection`:

inside `Client` class:

```
Private sumLosses As Collection 'the collection of numbers, a percentile of which I need to calculate

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sumLosses = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get getSumLosses()
    Set getSumLosses = sumLosses
End Property
```

**EDIT2:**

Changed the `Percentile` function call to this:

```
 Dim tempArray() As Variant
 tempArray = convertToArray(clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses)

 resultDict.Add "UL: " & _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(tempArray, 0.99)
```

the error occurs on the line with `resultDict`.

Comment: Collection? Do you mean a Range? What is the error that you got? Please give some details. Thanks

Comment: @nishit dey See edit.

Comment: Set some breakpoint in your function `convertToArray` to check what happened inside.

Comment: And make sure `clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses` is not empty.

Comment: @newacc2240 Now that I added `Debug.print` inside convert function, it looks like the function has finished and the error occures right after it.

Comment: Can you try withouth the `.item` in the line `clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses` as far as i know, Percentile uses an array not any single value.

Comment: @nishit dey, See edit. The `clientsColl.Item(1).getSumLosses` returns a collection with a lot of values - debug print proves it, I assign it to `tempArray`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. The adding to the dictionary was done in a wrong way:

`resultDict.Add "UL: " & _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(tempArray, 0.99)`

instead of

`resultDict.Add "UL: ", _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(tempArray, 0.99)`